# Overriding the function shouldInterceptRequest on Android

Tags: nativescript

I am not able to override the WebviewClient function shouldInterceptRequest on Android. Getting no error but the function is not called. What am i missing ?

Documentation for the function shouldInterceptRequest();
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

```
if(application.android){
    try{
        android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
              shouldInterceptRequest: function(_webView,webResourceRequest){
                    alert('shouldInterceptRequest is called');                            
                    return null;
             } 
       });
    }catch(e){                       
          alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you set your `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`. Try to do something like:

```
   var myWebView = page.getViewById("myWebView"); 
   if (myWebView.android) {
       try {
          var MyWebViewClient = android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
              shouldInterceptRequest: function(_webView,webResourceRequest){
                    alert('shouldInterceptRequest is called');                            
                    return null;
             } 
          });
          myWebView.android.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
       } catch(e) {                       
              alert(e.message);
       }
    }
```

Comment: great sample thanks a lot. It is working perfectly on webview. I was missing the line: myWebView.android.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());  There is a problem when used in combination with nativescript-webview-interface. https://github.com/shripalsoni04/nativescript-webview-interface. I will report the issue there. I get no error but content is not visible.